Automatically color all words starting with defined letters
I would like a way to specify a group of initial letters of words. Words beginning with that letter get automatically coloured red. I am aware of this but am not capable of adapting it to my need...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textbf{As stands}: This is a sample of a piece of text.

\textbf{Condition}: In the indicated part, make all words starting with (say)  letter a--g red. 

#Colouring starts 

\textbf{Desired output:} This is \textcolor{red}{a} sample of \textcolor{red}{a} \textcolor{red}{good} piece of text.

#Colouring ends

\end{document}


Why would the first a be colored and not the second?

Because I made a mistake...sorry. This is why I want it automated!

Ah, I thought I was just missing something. Sorry if my question came out as harsh.

Not at all, it was my mistake, don't worry

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It consists of a Lua function called colorize that does virtually all of the work, along with two utility LaTeX macros, called \colorizeOn and \colorizeOff, that initialize and terminate the assignment of the colorize function to LuaTeX's process_input_buffer callback.
The input requirements are

The macros \colorizeOn and \colorizeOff must occur on lines all by themselves.

Valid letters aren't required to be ASCII-encoded. General utf8-encoded letters are ok too.

Words in the test string are assumed to either start at the beginning of a line or to be preceded by whitespace. I haven't considered things like dashes, en-dashes, or em-dashes as separators between words. Let me know if this is an issue for you.

The text string should not contain LaTeX macros that might "hide" words that should be highlighted. E.g., no \textbf{abc}, please. I suppose that \textbf{ abc} would be ok, though, as the string "abc" is now preceded by whitespace.

I've assumed that words that start with either lowercase or uppercase letters in the range from a to g and from A to G should be colorized. If you want only words that start with lowercase letters in the range a thru g to be treated, just shorten both instances of the [a-gA-G] search pattern in the colorize function to [a-g].



% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}

  function colorize ( s )
    s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "^[a-gA-G]%w*", "\\textcolor{red}{%1}" ) -- word at start of line
    s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "%s[a-gA-G]%w*", " \\textcolor{red}{%1}" ) -- word preceded by whitespace
    return s 
  end

\end{luacode}

\newcommand\colorizeOn{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
     "process_input_buffer", colorize, "colorize")}}
\newcommand\colorizeOff{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
     "process_input_buffer", "colorize" )}}
     
\begin{document}
A sample of a piece of Good gentle text.

\colorizeOn
A sample of a piece of Good gentle text.
\colorizeOff

A sample of a piece of Good gentle text.

\end{document}


Addendum: In my answer, I've assumed that "words" may contain any alphanumerical characters. If they're supposed to consist of alphabetical characters only, just replace both instances of %w* with %a*.

Outstanding, thank you very much
